# Table joins across servers, generic method

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, oledb

I've yet to see an application like MS Access that will let you link to tables on remote servers, of a variety of technologies, and then perform queries that include joins across these disparate sources. I find it somewhat amazing that Access can link up to a table on Sql Server, another on Oracle, or even a local file-based DB, and then allow queries to be performed joining them.

So my programming related question is: If one were to develop software that could do this, how should one go about doing this? Does Access use some inbuilt feature of existing DB technology to do this? Ie, does OleDB or ODBC or some technology have this built in, or is Access doing a lot of proprietary heavy lifting on its own?

If Access is doing all this work itself, it seems this would be a rather difficult thing to reproduce in a new project. I'm just curious what level of complexity we're talking about here, and whether some existing layer of DB tech already has this inbuilt.

Comment: I should add - is this ability built into the Jet engine somehow?

Comment: AFAIK, Access transfers and executes all the data from all those datasources locally. This is great in terms of generic access but it kills performance.

Comment: @Lieven Access only gets the data locally if it cannot take advantage of indexes such as when a query is badly designed.

Comment: @Remou - Data from different datasources? How would Access know how to join SQLServer.TableA with Oracle.TableB without getting all relevent data local?

Comment: @Lieven I thought you were talking about the common misconception that MS Access always transfers the whole table :) ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722917.aspx )

Comment: @Remou - That was indeed not clear from my comment.

Comment: ok, so does the jet engine have this intelligence built in, or is it specifically in access? Any idea of other product that does this same sort of thing? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The task of joining tables from different data sources is harder than it looks even if you just restrict yourself to a single database API (like ODBC). ODBC has nothing built in to accomplice this. Look at ODBC's SQLGetInfo, SQLGetConnectAttr and SQLGetStatementAttr APIs and you'll see the possible differences between ODBC drivers.

There is an SQLEngine for Windows which will join different ODBC data sources which can all be to different databases at [ODBC-ODBC Join Engine](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_join_engine/index.html)

UPDATE: Disclosure - I work for Easysoft.

Comment: I forgot the disclosure - sorry - corrected. Of my 90 answers you'll see I am not in the habit of promoting our software and this is an answer.

Comment: bohica, would you say the jet engine in access is what does the same that this product does? thanks

Comment: Yes. There is certainly nothing in ODBC to do this. BTW, if you decide to write something like it best of luck. In particular group by and sorting etc will be a PITA. Beyond that if you use ODBC you'll be amazed at just how different each driver can behave (see those API calls I mentioned in my answer).